# In this assignment you will ask the user to input an English word, translate that word into ”Pig Latin” and then print both words

Tags: python

I have this assignment due for my computer science class:

In this assignment you will ask the user to input an English word, translate that word into ”Pig Latin” and then print both words.

These are the rules:

1. If a word starts with a vowel (a, A, e, E, i, I, o, O, u, U) then the translation is formed by adding a "way" to the end of the word. e.g. "at" becomes "atway", "egg" becomes "eggway"
2. If a word contains no vowels (a, A, e, E, i, I, o, O, u, U) then the translation is formed by a adding a "way" to the end of word. e.g. "my" becomes "myway", "by" becomes "byway"
3. If a word starts with a consonant and contains a vowel, the translation is formed by moving the consonant(s) up to the first vowel to the end of the word and adding an "ay". e.g. "bat" becomes "atbay", "that" becomes "atthay", "three" becomes "eethray"
4. Words that start with an initial capital letter should be translated to words with an initial capital letter. e.g. "Houston" becomed "Oustonhay", "Iceland" becomes "Icelandway", "Marry" becomes "Arrymay"

This is the programming I have so far. I am stuck on the 3rd and 4th rule:

```
def is_vowel(letter):
    return letter.upper() in 'AEIOU'

def has_vowel(word):
    for letter in word:
        if is_vowel(letter):
            return True 
    return False

def translate(word):
    if is_vowel(word[0]): #is the first letter
        return word + "way"
    elif has_vowel(word):
        pass
    else: #there is no vowel
        return word + "way"

#stuff before the loop
print("This program will translate a word from English to Pig Latin.")
choice = "Y"

#stuff in the loop
while choice.upper() == 'Y':
    word = input("Please enter a word: ")
    print(word, "becomes", translate(word) + ".")
    choice = input("Would you like another word? (Y/N) ")

#stuff after the loop
print("Ankthay ouyay!")
```

I know this is right because we did this part in class but when I came home I was completely lost and unsure what I need to do! Please help!

Comment: First of all, your indentation is wrong (such as after your `if` and `elif`), and it matters in Python. Please fix it.

Comment: just updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third rule requires you to find the index of the first vowel and then *flip* the characters around. There are several ways to find the index of a first vowel but I reckon this is the one you'll understand the best:

```
def get_vowel_index(word):
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):  # use enumerate() to iterate over index, value pairs
        if letter.upper() in 'AEIOU':
            return i  # return the index
```

Now you can use this function to find the vowel index and then slice the word so it matches your third rule, e.g.:

```
word = "that"
index = get_vowel_index(word)
pl_word = word[index:] + word[:index] + "ay"
print(pl_word)  # atthay
```

You can even use this function instead of your other functions as it will return `None` if there are no vowels in the word or the index if there is some so by simple checking the return of this function you can check all three conditions. This gives you a way to optimize your code a bit as the rules are exclusive so you can rewrite your `translate()` function as:

```
def translate(word):
    vowel_index = get_vowel_index(word)  # get the vowel index
    # the rule for the vowel as the first letter and no vowels is the same:
    if vowel_index == 0 or vowel_index is None:
        return word + "way"
    # otherwise there is a vowel in the word, flip the consonants to the end:
    return word[vowel_index:] + word[:vowel_index] + "ay"
```

And you can easily test it with:

```
for v in ("at", "egg", "my", "by", "bat", "that", "three"):
    print(translate(v))
```

Which will produce:

```
atway
eggway
myway
byway
atbay
atthay
eethray
```

As for the fourth rule, all you need is to check if the first letter was uppercase in the third condition (as the first two keep the letters unshuffled) and turn it into a titlecase (check [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)) if it was. So, to complete the `translation()` function, you can do something like:

```
def translate(word):
    index = get_vowel_index(word)  # get the vowel index
    if index == 0 or index is None:
        return word + "way"
    # otherwise there is a vowel in the word, flip the consonants to the end
    if word[0].isupper():  # the first letter was uppercase
        return (word[index:] + word[:index] + "ay").title()  # title-case it!
    return word[index:] + word[:index] + "ay"
```

And to test it:

```
for v in ("Houston", "Iceland", "Marry"):
    print(translate(v))
```

Yielding:

```
Oustonhay
Icelandway
Arrymay
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a kind of homework assignment, I am not writnig code (a commendable practice on SO).

Rule 3 should consist in finding which character is the first vowel, and then moving the slice of word from beginning up to that character to the end of the word (technically you would replace the string with two slices, as strings are immutable in python) and then append the "ay"

Rule 4: if upper case of the first letter of word (before any modifications) is the same as that letter, then save that info into some variable and based on that change (or not) the first letter of output